# R: one part of code in if statement doesn't execute

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to transform my original data into start-stop format for Cox regression. My original dataset is like this:

```
df = data.frame(initial = c(25, 25, 20, 21, 21, 17), 
                total = c(4.25, 28, 0.5, 38, 14, 43), 
                age = c(30, 53, 20, 59, 35, 60), 
                ethanol = c(0.04, 0.306, 0.201, 0.222, 0.047, 0.085), 
                status = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

For example, for the first observation, the original data format like this:

```
    initial  total  age  ethanol  status
 1  25       4.25   30    0.04    0
```

The expected data format is like:

```
 id  start  stop     ethanol  status
 1   0.00   25.00    0.00     0
 1   25.00  29.25    0.04     0
 1   29.25  30       0        0
```

So I write codes as below

```
edf = data.frame(id = integer(), 
                 start = numeric(), 
                 stop = numeric(), 
                 ethanol = numeric(),
                 status = integer())

j = 1

for( i in 1:4){

  if( (df[i, 1] + df[i,2]) >= df[i,3] ){
    edf[j,1] = i
    edf[j,2] = 0
    edf[j,3] = df[i,"initial"]
    edf[j,4] = 0
    edf[j,5] = 0
    j = j+1
    edf[j,1] = i
    edf[j,2] = df[i,"initial"]
    edf[j,3] = df[i,"initial"] + df[i,"total"]
    edf[j,4] = df[i,"ethanol"]
    edf[j,5] = df[i,"status"]
  } else{
    edf[j,1] = i
    edf[j,2] = 0
    edf[j,3] = df[i,"initial"]
    edf[j,4] = 0
    edf[j,5] = 0

    j = j+1
    edf[j,1] = i
    edf[j,2] = df[i,"initial"]
    edf[j,3] = df[i,"initial"] + df[i,"total"]
    edf[j,4] = df[i,"ethanol"]
    edf[j,5] = 0

    j = j+1
    edf[j,1] = i
    edf[j,2] = df[i,"initial"] + df[i,"total"]
    edf[j,3] = df[i,"age"]
    edf[j,4] = 0
    edf[j,5] = df[i,"status"]
  }
}
```

But the data frame that I got is (for example, the first observation):

```
 id     start    stop    ethanol  status
 1      0.00     25.00   0.00     0
 1      25.00    29.25   0.04     0
```

One row is missing:

```
id  start    stop    ethanol  status
1   29.25    30      0        0
```

It seems that the last part in the else-statement hasn't been executed:

```
    j = j+1
    edf[j,1] = i
    edf[j,2] = df[i,"initial"] + df[i,"total"]
    edf[j,3] = df[i,"age"]
    edf[j,4] = 0
    edf[j,5] = df[i,"status"]
```

I don't know what's wrong, Any suggestion?
I use R version 3.4.4 on MacOS (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0.)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not incrementing `j`, the row number, before writing the first row in each iteration of the loop. Consequently, you are writing over the previous row each time. The following will work.

```
j = 0

for( i in 1:4){
  j = j + 1
  if( (df[i, 1] + df[i,2]) >= df[i,3] ){
    edf[j,1] = i
    edf[j,2] = 0
    edf[j,3] = df[i,"initial"]
    edf[j,4] = 0
    edf[j,5] = 0
    j = j+1
    edf[j,1] = i
    edf[j,2] = df[i,"initial"]
    edf[j,3] = df[i,"initial"] + df[i,"total"]
    edf[j,4] = df[i,"ethanol"]
    edf[j,5] = df[i,"status"]
  } else{
    edf[j,1] = i
    edf[j,2] = 0
    edf[j,3] = df[i,"initial"]
    edf[j,4] = 0
    edf[j,5] = 0

    j = j+1
    edf[j,1] = i
    edf[j,2] = df[i,"initial"]
    edf[j,3] = df[i,"initial"] + df[i,"total"]
    edf[j,4] = df[i,"ethanol"]
    edf[j,5] = 0

    j = j+1
    edf[j,1] = i
    edf[j,2] = df[i,"initial"] + df[i,"total"]
    edf[j,3] = df[i,"age"]
    edf[j,4] = 0
    edf[j,5] = df[i,"status"]
  }
}
```

Edit: there are better ways of doing this. There is probably some package that can reshape the data more easily. Or you could create the three start/stop steps as separate data frames and then merge them. Failing that, you can at least simplify like this:

```
df$end = df$initial + df$total
for (i in rownames(df)) {
    r = df[i,]
    edf[nrow(edf) + 1,] = list(i, 0, r$initial, 0, 0)
    if (r$end >= r$age){
      edf[nrow(edf) + 1,] = list(i, r$initial, r$end, r$ethanol, r$status)
    }
    else {
      edf[nrow(edf) + 1,] = list(i, r$initial, r$end, r$ethanol, 0)
      edf[nrow(edf) + 1,] = list(i, r$end, r$age, 0, r$status)
    }
}
```